# On convex quadratic programming clarification

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, convexity, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

We know convex quadratic programming is in $P$.

> Is it also in $P$ if the function of interest is only convex in the domain of interest?

Comment: Could you ask a more precise question? E.g., trivially speaking, if the domain of interest is not convex then the problem can be easily NP-Hard, for intance, binary QP, where the domain of interest is $\{\pm1\}$. If the domain is convex, but not easy to test membership in, even then membership in $P$ may fail ....